# Simple regular expression modification to match only images

Tags: php, regex

How can I edit the following regex

```
/(?<=src=")(.*?)(?=")/ui
```

to get only the matches that ends to jpeg, png, gif like the one below?

```
!http://.+\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif)!Ui
```

Thank you

Comment: please explain a bit more about what you are trying to accomplish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/(?<=src=")([^"]+\.(jpe?g|png|gif))(?=")/ui
```

Replace the .* in the middle ( it represents file name ) - so this will match only if file name ends with jpg, jpeg, png, gif

EDIT:

Solutin with query string is :

```
/(?<=src=")([^"]+\.(jpe?g|png|gif))(\?[^"]*)?(?=")/ui
```

And i replaced . with [^"], because double quote is invalid in URI ( and not used often ) - or you can use this ([^"]|(?<=\)|") for escaped double quote

Comment: Is there any solution for this type of url ? `www.domain.com/media/k2/items/cache/98fa1e7f44a7213e727a7cb29f736fdb_L.jpg?timestamp=1307719333` The code I posted, gets those images.

Answer (score 1):

And in place of the catch-all `(.*?)` use `([^"]+)` preferrably.

Comment: Can you please explain me the difference ?

Comment: The catch-all matches everything, and might accidently eat up two image strings in a single line. The second is a negated character class and only matches everything but double quotes - which is what you need since the searched string must always be enclosed in double quotes for your case anyway. -- Well see what SergeS updated now, that's exactly how it should read.